# How to pull 2 results from PHP Mysql with AJAX and json

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, json

Hello guys i need the following help code,

I am trying to pull 2 different results from mysql php to ajax using json.

Here is what I have at the moment.

I can pull 1 table with information but dont know how to pull 2 different results. Please help me.

PHP file

```
    $id = $_POST["order"];

    $order = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE `order_id` = {$id} ORDER BY id DESC");

    $test_quote = mysql_query("
                        SELECT paid
                        FROM `outstanding`
                        WHERE order_id = {$id}
                        ");
    $array = array();

//pulling outstanding if product paid or not                    
    if(mysql_num_rows($test_quote) > 0 ){
        $array[] =  mysql_fetch_array($test_quote);
    }



    //pulling products
    if (mysql_num_rows($order) > 0){ 

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($order)){

            $array[] = $row;

        } 



    } else { echo "<div style='font-size:12px;'>No orders yet</div>";}

    echo json_encode($array);
```

Its pulling 1 query but cant get another query from php file

jQuery

```
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "order_load.php",
              data: {order : thisId},
              dataType:"json",    
              success: function(data){

                  $.each(data, function(i, val){

                      var append2 = '<div class="product">';
                        append2 +='<div class="view_left2">';
                        append2 +='<b>Item ID:</b> ';
                        append2 +='#'+val.id;
                        append2 +='</div>';
                        append2 +='<div class="line"><img src="images/productLine.png" /></div>';
                        append2 +='<div class="viewleft3">'+val.desc+'</div>';
                        append2 +='<div class="right_order">';
                        append2 +='<div class="line"><img src="images/productLine.png" /></div>';
                        append2 +='<div class="view_right2">';
                        append2 +='<div class="price3">$'+val.amount+'</div></div><div class="clear"></div></div>';
                        append2 +='<div class="clear"></div></div>';
                        $(".view_product2").append(append2);
                  });
```

This is my json output:

```
[{"0":"1","paid":"1"},{"0":"336","id":"336","1":"1","qty":"1","2":"sdfgsdf","desc":"sdfgsdf","3":"yes","gst":"yes","4":"44","price":"44","5":"44.00","amount":"44.00","6":"225","order_id":"225"}]
```

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/q0gwD). See the [red box](http://goo.gl/OWwr2)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/orrj0) and use either [PDO](http://goo.gl/TD3xh) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/YXyWL) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/b2ATO). Also see [Why shouldn't I use mysql functions in PHP?](http://goo.gl/J5jAo)

Comment: Also, I really hope this website isn't live, as its vulnerable to injection attacks.

Comment: guys you picking on so small things here, I am trying to get help with the code and I know I have to do mysql_real_escape_string. and I am using normal MySQL.

Comment: Hope someone can help me with the code not being smart ass here.

Comment: There's only one of me.  And `mysql_real_escape_string()` or not, I really suggest you learn to use PDO, instead of something that will disappear with the next major release.

Comment: Thanks mate, I really need help with this code and PDO i can do next time when I finish this code. I already done alot of work on this CMS

Comment: Perhaps this is a stupid question, but have you done any of the necessary debugging steps?  Checking to be sure the query returns results, making sure the json contains the necessary data; visiting the page that echos the json to make sure it contains what it needs to.. Your question is lacking in information, such as example data..  json results, etc.  This is information needed to reproduce the problem and find the cause.

Comment: Ok I just listed the jSOn that I am getting

Answer (score 1):

There are several things wrong with your code.  Firstly; you refer to a non-existent json property from your returned json, `.amount`.  I've changed that to `.price` to return the correct result.

Secondly..

Your returned json is an array of objects.  To access the `.paid` property, you need to refer to the first item of the array before you can access and set the `paid` variable.. which you never do.

```
var paid = data[0].paid; // set the paid variable per its placement in the json

$.each(data, function (i, val) {
    if (i != 0) { // check to make sure it isn't the first object of the array
        var append2 = '<div class="product">';
        append2 += '<div class="view_left2">';
        append2 += '<b>Item ID:</b> ';
        append2 += '#' + val.id;
        append2 += '</div>';
        append2 += '<div class="line"><img src="images/productLine.png" /></div>';
        append2 += '<div class="viewleft3">' + val.desc + '</div>';
        append2 += '<div class="right_order">';
        append2 += '<div class="line"><img src="images/productLine.png" /></div>';
        append2 += '<div class="view_right2">';
        append2 += '<div class="price3">$' + val.price + '</div></div><div class="clear"></div></div>';
        //                                       ^ use the correct json property to access the value.  It is not amount.
        append2 += '<div class="clear"></div></div>';
        $(".view_product2").append(append2);
    }
});
```

Comment: val.amount is from my database and its working but I cant get 2nd result, I want second result to be in $("#div").html(second result to be here);

Comment: @EddyBlackpool With the json you gave me, there is no second result.  Not to mention that with the SQL you used, there wouldn't be.. unless that is, you're giving multiple records the same order id.  Without the table structure information, and example data, I'm shooting in the dark here.

Comment: what information would you like to provide you to help me out?

Comment: @EddyBlackpool Table structure and example data.  Aside from that, you changed your json structure early on; was it different from what you originally posted?  I ask because my original answer addressed that original json.. so..

Comment: dont worry looks like too much problem in this code. I just bloody google it then.